# How to attach response header in VTL template

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-appsync, response-headers, vtl

My application is in `serverless` framework and I am using `vtl` template as a `lambda resolver`. My app stack is `AppSync`, `Lambda` on `Node JS` runtime, `Serverless` framework and `vtl` templates.
I am trying to figure how I can add custom `response headers` from my lambda to client and really appreciate any input on the same. Please find my code below so far:

**Lambda**

```
const securityHeaders = {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate",
    };
    
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: securityHeaders,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data,
      })
    });

  return;
```

**serverless yml**

```
functions:
  getData:
    handler: src/handler.getData
    events:
      - http:
          path: getData
          method: post    
custom:
  configValidationMode: off
  appSync:
    schema: ['graphql-schemas/data.graphql']
    authenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
    mappingTemplates:
      - dataSource: GetData
        type: Query
        field: getData
        request: "data-request.vtl"
        response: "data-response.vtl"
```

**data-response.vtl**

```
## return the body
#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
    ##if response is 200
    $ctx.result.body
#else
    ##if response is not 200, append the response to error block.
    $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

The above code giving me the result in the postman but I am not able to see my custom headers in the response section. I think I am missing on how to include headers in the response vtl.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but still I also need to add same response headers in Every GraphQL operation. Please refer https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/02/aws-appsync-support-custom-response-headers/ and https://docs.amazonaws.cn/appsync/latest/devguide/http-helpers-in-utils-http.html.

I created VTL template and attached to each resolver in responseMappingTemplate. It works for me.